# Best algorithm to solve eigenvalue problem.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is my first post.

I need to solve this:

$$ A\bf{x} = x\lambda$$

A classical eigenvalue problem. The thing is that I need the best algorithm that allows good parallelization (GPU). I was thinking about the Conjugated Gradient Method, but one of my thesis reviewers told me that perhaps it wouldn't be the best algorithm but he didn't suggest one either. Could you guys suggest me something o give me a hint?

Comment: How big are your matrices? Are they sparse or dense?  Is A Hermitian?

Comment: Sorry for don't be explicit. My matrices come from a Finite Element treatment, so they are very big but are sparse. My problem comes from the quantum chemistry and the eigenvalues represent my orbital energies, so I don't need to find all the eigenvalues just a number of interest that represents my occupied orbitals.

Comment: Please update your question to include that information and be a bit more quantitative about the matrix size and sparsity.  Is $n$ in the hundreds of thousands?  millions?  Are the matrices 5% dense?  0.0005% dense?  Do you want largest eigenvalues, smallest eigenvalues, eigenvalues closest to a specified value?